# CyanogenMod Boot Animation Squished

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-animation

I recently installed CyanogenMod (nightly) on my tablet. I like it and it runs much faster than Android ever did. But when it boots, for the first 5 or so seconds, the (portrait) boot animation is stretched so that it takes up half of the screen vertically and extends to around double the width horizontally (almost like it defaults to landscape sizes or something?). After the first few seconds, it fixes itself and looks normal.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

It's a Samsung galaxy tab 2 7.0 (p3113).

Comment: Realistically, it's probably just a bug in the nightly. The CM team will work it out in time, but until then there's not a lot (if anything) you can really do other than switch to something "stable" if it bothers you.

Comment: OK... I had tried to use the built-in updater to revert to the most recent stable build but something that they did makes it break when I revert. It's not much of a problem for me it just seemed like it was a tablet-specific issue and I wanted to see if anyone else knew of a solution.